# What type of wire does transmission tower use?

Tags: transmission-line

I learn form a more than 20years old book(South Korea text book) that high voltage transmission towers take `Bare wire` into service. But I saw some company take `Insulated wire` into service.

Question : What type of wire is using in high voltage transmission-wire?

Comment: Whenever possible its useful to include the references of where you got your info.

Comment: from what you said, the answer is `both`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, uninsulated wire. We're talking about these 30–100m high towers, right?

[image: "Freileitung" in Germany]

<sup>License: CC-by-SA 4.0, photograph "-wuppertaler"</sup>

They are high for a reason, and every bit of insulation (and you'd need *a lot* of isolation for 380 kV) adds weight that makes the whole system mechanically harder to build.

---

If we're talking about the 3m high poles with which individual houses are connected: yes, these are more commonly isolated cable instead of three uninsulated wires.

Formerly: Uninsulated low-voltage distribution to houses:

[image: Freileitung low voltage (230V)]
<sup>License: CC-by-SA 2.5, photograph "Joddel"</sup>

Now, much more common: Insulated cabling.

[image: Insulated wires on a mast carrying also a transformer]
<sup>License: CC-by 3.0, photograph "wdwd"</sup>

---

All Images from Wikimedia commons, linked to the respective commons site with usage/license information.

Comment: Often Aluminium-conductor steel-reinforced cable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium-conductor_steel-reinforced_cable

Comment: In suburban New Zealand (at least) and many other places, we seem to have transmission lines with what I assume is medium-voltage three-phase uninsulated wire higher up, and low-voltage single-phase below.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

Insulation has two primary purposes:

- **Protect against short circuits** by preventing conductors touching each other.
- **Protect against electric shock**.

At high voltages, 100 kV to 400 kV the insulation required would be heavy and expensive. It's also not required as the cables are high above the ground. For this we use air as the insulator. It has the BIG advantage that it is **free**.

Lower voltage lines are installed much closer to the ground and can be hit by tree branches, trucks and humans much more easily. Only 1 mm or so of insulation is required so it doesn't add much weight so it is often used. At my house the incoming 230 V live wire is insulated but the neutral is not. (The neutral has been connected to earth at the transformer so there should never be a high voltage on the neutral wire.)